# Compare two div contents and hide an element

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to hide read more text to be appear if the contents are eqaual between two divs.
if content of `.less-cont` and `.more-cont` equal hiding `.more`.
pls advice

```
 <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12"><strong>subject</strong></div>
                                        <div class="disp-cont col-md-auto">
                                             Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing an
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="more-cont col-md-auto" style="display:none;">
                                          
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s

                                    </div>
                                    <a href="#" class="more col-md-auto">read more</a>
                               
                                <div class="col-md-12">no record</div>
                                
                            </div>
```

I tried below,
but didn't work as expected

```
$( ".row" ).each(function( index ) {
var one = $.trim($(this).closest('.more-cont').text());
var two = $.trim($( this ).closest('.disp-cont').text());
 if(one === two){
$(this).closest('.more').hide();
} 

});
```

Comment: You would like to compare the length of words from ```.disp-cont``` with ```.more-cont```? If ```.more-cont``` is the less or the same length as ```.disp-cont``` you want to display it all together, otherwise you want to hide the ```.more-cont``` and show the ```.more``` link. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the length of the `text()` of each of those elements.

```js
$('.row').each(function() {
    
  let _this = $(this),
      dispC = _this.children('.disp-cont'),
      moreC = _this.children('.more-cont'),
      moreBtn = _this.children('.more');
      
  if(moreC.text().length > dispC.text().length){
    // add toggle function here
    moreBtn.on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      moreC.slideDown();
      moreBtn.hide();
    });
  } else {
    moreC.show();
    moreBtn.hide();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Read more example where "more content" has more characters:</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><strong>subject</strong></div>
    <div class="disp-cont col-md-auto">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing an
    </div>
    <div class="more-cont col-md-auto" style="display:none;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more col-md-auto">read more</a>
    <div class="col-md-12">no record</div>
</div>

<h2>Read more example where "more content" is equal to "display content"</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><strong>subject</strong></div>
    <div class="disp-cont col-md-auto">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing an
    </div>
    <div class="more-cont col-md-auto" style="display:none;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing an
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more col-md-auto">read more</a>
    <div class="col-md-12">no record</div>
</div>

<h2>Read more example where "more content" is less than "display content"</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><strong>subject</strong></div>
    <div class="disp-cont col-md-auto">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing an
    </div>
    <div class="more-cont col-md-auto" style="display:none;">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="more col-md-auto">read more</a>
    <div class="col-md-12">no record</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?